# Difficulty Merging Excel Files with Varying Rows and Values in Columns

Tags: excel, merge

I work in higher education and am attempting to create a dashboard of the school's enrollment numbers (headcount and credit hours) by term, degree program, and campus. Part of the difficulty is that the only way I can pull the data is by term (Fall, Spring, and Summer) so that I end up with three separate excel spreadsheets I need to merge.

[A sample of the Falls spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c1Ye.png)

The column headers with a number/letter string are the terms by head count ("hc") and credit hour ("ch")
A string beginning with "F" stands for Fall term, "S" for Spring, and "U" for Summer. The two digits following the first letter are the year. For example a header with "F21 hc" would be the headcount of Fall 2021. The column under the header "Group" contains the degree programs.

To further complicate things, each spreadsheet contains a different number of rows because some degree programs were started or discontinued during different terms, and they're not even in the same order.

[Falls Spreadsheet sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16cJe.png)

[Springs Spreadsheet sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KchR.png)

[Summers Spreadsheet sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMoVv.png)

What I tried initially was a tedious process of comparing one spreadsheet's degree programs with another. First I copy/pasted all the spreadsheets' full list of degree programs into one column, and used UNIQUE to find all the distinct values. Then, I made it so that every campus would have a correlation with every degree program, even if the enrollment numbers were 0 across the board. Once that was the case on each of the three spreadsheets, copy and pasted all the term headcount (hc) and credit hour (ch) columns onto one spreadsheet, since they all now had the same number of rows.

The process was so convoluted that it resulted in some errors and missing or mismatched data. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of going about this that doesn't put it at so much risk for human error and saves a lot more time?

Comment: `Power Query` would be right to use here.

Comment: If Power Query is not practical, another approach would be to add a new column on each sheet with a unique key for each Campus/Group value, for example "Campus 1_M.Div.", "Online_ThM", etc. on each of your 3 sheets and on your new sheet. Then you can use that unique key value to VLOOKUP / XLOOKUP the numbers from each sheet.

Comment: when combining the data, is there a column that indicate the source semester's date/season?

Comment: p._phidot, there is not. The only thing that indicates the semester date/season are the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, Power Query was the way to go.

Essentially, I was able to download the data for head count and credit hour separately. Then, using Power Query, I merged all the data for head count together, then merged all the data for credit hour together.

From there, I cleaned the credit hour data, then copy/pasted the steps from that cleaning into the Advanced Editor for the head count data query (changing some the instances of "credit hour" to "head count"). Finally, I merged the two queries into one, and now I have both head count and credit hour data on one spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi, you provided a very useful answer. However, maybe you can add an example which would make your answer even better to understand.